# How to calculate force exerted in a pedal operated power hammer.

Tags: forces, energy

[image]
I just made a pedal operated power hammer project its hammer head weight's 14kg falling from a height of 25 cm how to calculate force exerted on the work piece.

Comment: If you can take a video of it in slow motion, measuring the change in momentum of the hammer head and dividing by the collision time will give you the average force exerted in the collision.

Comment: This looks like a bit of an odd design, because it appears the hammer is pulled down by weight applied to the pedal (and the spring negates the weight of the hammer head itself). That means the force will be very dependent on how much weight is applied to the pedal.
On of the issues with this design is that, say, your leg, will experience the peak hammering force on impact (a health issue). Most hammering machines put energy in, and then the 'drive' is disconnected in some way, such that it does not experience the peak force. For example, a pile driver.

Comment: I'd expect the design to have the hammer lifted, and then locked by the pedal, and the pedal release the lock so the hamer drops or is pulled by springs onto the target.